# Insert Record with Rest api and one wrong field

Tags: api, rest

when insert a record into salesforce and the JSON file contains one field from backend, which may not yet be in Salesforce, is it possible, that the record will be created with the correct field and leave out the missing one, instead of giving an error msg and not insert?

Example when trying to insert a person account:
{
"Firstname":"John",
"Lastname": "Doe",
"recordTypeId": "0127R0000007XXXXX",
"AccessRestricted__c":"true"
}

And let's say Field "AccessRestricted__c" is not in Salesforce. Is there a way, that the record is nevertheless inserted, just leaving out this field?

Thanks
RRI

Comment: This question needs some elaboration with more details - the input JSON and corresponding SFDC schema. Use [edit]

Comment: Added an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, if the caller is using the OOTB SFDC REST Api to insert an Sobject, all fields in the JSON payload need to be visible to the running user (the API user)

You can work around this if :

- you change the endpoint to a [custom APEX Rest](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_rest.htm?search_text=apex%20rest) endpoint
- where the input can be parsed from a `Map<String,Object>` and
- the map keys can be compared against [SObjectDescribe](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_dynamic_describe_objects_understanding.htm?search_text=describe) and
- fields not known to the schema can be ignored before the Apex REST service does a Database.insert.

To avoid hardcoding any fieldnames, use the [Sobject class put method](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.230.0.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm)